# Laravel displaying/updating data from DB show data in view only status "active" and "deactive" find by $id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I tried below code, but it is not working.

In this code, when I entered "DELETED", "id" number in browser "URL" it showing "DELETED" status users details also, I want to show and access only "ACTIVATE" AND "DEACTIVATE" users only if I entered "DELETED" Users "id" in "URL" it should show an error:

```php
public function staff_status($id)
{
    $user = User::where('status', '=', 'ACTIVATE')->orWhere('status', '=', 'DEACTIVATE')->find($id);

    return view('home', compact('user'));
}

public function status_update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::where('status', '=', 'ACTIVATE') > orWhere('status', '=', 'DEACTIVATE')->find($id);

    $user['status'] = $request->status;

    $user->save();

    return back()->with('success', 'SUBMITED SUCCESSFULLY .');
}
```

Comment: Add another condition `->where('status', '!=', 'DELETED')->findOrFail($id)`

Comment: @Chay22  for this code ? $user=User::where('status','=','ACTIVATE')->orWhere('status','=','DEACTIVATE')->find($id);

Comment: Instead of `orWhere` use another `where`. `User::where('status', 'ACTIVATE')->where('status', 'DEACTIVATE')->find($id);` if you want to return both active & deleted users

Comment: @Chay22                                                                                                                      error                                                                                                                                "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Chay22 mentioned you're supposed to add another where condition

just replace your code with this

```
public function staff_status($id)
{
    $user = User::where('status', '!=', 'DELETED')
                  ->where(function($query){
                      $query->where('status','=','ACTIVATE');
                      $query->orWhere('status','=','DEACTIVATE');
                  })->find($id);
    if (! $user) {
        return // return your error here
    }

    return view('home',compact('user'));
}

public function status_update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::where('status', '!=', 'DELETED')
                  ->where(function($query){
                      $query->where('status','=','ACTIVATE');
                      $query->orWhere('status','=','DEACTIVATE');
                  })->find($id);

    if ($user) {
        $user->status = $request->status;
        $user->save();

        return back()->with('success','SUBMITED SUCCESSFULLY .');
    } else {
        return // return your error here
    }
}
```

Comment: showing error                                                                                                                 "syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE)"

Comment: @RamuRamu the `;` is missing on nested where, I've updated the answer